# Does the Arcane Strike feat allow you to hit incorporeal creatures?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, magic, incorporeal

The [Arcane Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/arcane-strike-combat/) feat says that

> your weapons [...] are treated as magic for the purpose of overcoming damage reduction.

I do not read this as suggesting that a mundane weapon actually becomes magical - for instance, it would presumably still not be found by *detect magic*.

An [incorporeal creature](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Incorporeal_Ex) is "immune to all nonmagical attack forms", and can only be struck by "magic weapons".

Does this mean that with Arcane Strike, an otherwise nonmagical weapon can be effective against an incorporeal enemy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. [Per an FAQ from Halloween 2014](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fo#v5748eaic9sih), effects which make a weapon count as magical for DR allow it to hit incorporeal creatures.

Comment: "No"?  do you mean "Yes"?

Comment: Yes. At the time, the body of Hydrothermal's question asked the question the other way round to the title. I've edited my response now.